# How would I design this scenario in Twilio?

Tags: ruby, sms, sinatra, twilio

I'm working on a [YRS 2013](https://youngrewiredstate.org/) project and would like to use Twilio. I already have a Twilio account set up with over $100 worth of funds on it. I am working on a project which uses an external API and finds events near a location and date. The project is written in Ruby using Sinatra (which is going to be deployed to Heroku).

I am wondering whether you guys could guide me on how to approach this scenario: a user texts to the number of my Twilio account (the message would contain the location and date data), we process the body of that sms, and send back the results to the number that asked for them. I'm not sure where to start; for example if Twilio would handle some of that task or I would just use Twilio's API and do checking for smss and returning the results. I thinking about not using a database.

Could you guide me on how to approach this task?

*I need to present the project on Friday; so I'm on a tight deadline! Thanks for our help.*

Comment: Just to sum this up, a user texts a number and they receive a text back with the location and time. Are you handling multiple events or is this just one event?

Comment: A user texts a location and time, and we send back events happening on that time and in that location. What do you mean by multiple events?

Comment: So a user would text Boston 5pm and your system would return a text message with events x,y and z are occurring at that time? Where would you be getting your events from? why are you trying to stay away from a database? What kind of data structure are you thinking of using to store the events, times, and locations? Are you planning on having them respond in a certain manner to make it easier to look reply? (Such as City, time(military or standard(if standard them put PM or AM after?)))

Comment: The project I have written is done. It is a web app. On there, the user can enter a location, and date and the web app will take data from an external API matching the parameters described by the user and display them. I have the processing system fully working. All I need to get working is the SMS side of things. I'm just not sure how to approach the design behind the SMS messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have some great [documentation](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/hello-monkey) on how to do most of this.

When you receive a text you should parse it into the format you need

Put it into your existing project and when it returns the event or events in the area you need to check how long the string is due to a constraint that twilio has of restricting messages to 160 characters or less.

Ensure that you split the message elegantly and not in the middle of an event. If you were returned "Boston Celtics Game", "The Nut Cracker Play". you want to make sure that if both events cannot be put in one message that the first message says "Boston Celtics Game, Another text coming in 1 second" Or something similar.

---

In order to receive a text message from a mobile device, you'll have to expose an endpoint that is reachable by Twilio. Here is an example

```
class ReceiveTextController < ActionController
  def index 
    # let's pretend that we've mapped this action to 
    # http://localhost:3000/sms in the routes.rb file

    message_body = params["Body"]
    from_number = params["From"]

    SMSLogger.log_text_message from_number, message_body
  end
end
```

In this example, the index action receives a POST from Twilio. It grabs the message body, and the phone number of the sender and logs it. Retrieving the information from the Twilio POST is as simple as looking at the params hash

```
{
  "AccountSid"=>"asdf876a87f87a6sdf876876asd8f76a8sdf595asdD",
  "Body"=> body,
  "ToZip"=>"94949",
  "FromState"=>"MI",
  "ToCity"=>"NOVATO",
  "SmsSid"=>"asd8676585a78sd5f548a64sd4f64a467sg4g858",
  "ToState"=>"CA",
  "To"=>"5555992673",
  "ToCountry"=>"US",
  "FromCountry"=>"US",
  "SmsMessageSid"=>"hjk87h9j8k79hj8k7h97j7k9hj8k7",
  "ApiVersion"=>"2008-08-01",
  "FromCity"=>"GRAND RAPIDS",
  "SmsStatus"=>"received",
  "From"=>"5555992673",
  "FromZip"=>"49507"
}
```

[Source](http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2012/01/20/twilio-on-rails/)

Comment: Yes! How would I get the body of the incoming SMS though?

Comment: It is pretty easy, I updated with a quick example and a link to the tutorial that I used.